# Trying to implement a Behavior Extension in WCF

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf

I am attempting to add a custom SOAP header in WCF in order to provide more information about the status to the client's request.

I've referenced a number of examples of how to implement a behavior extension in order to do this.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mohamedg/2012/10/21/adding-custom-soap-headers-in-wcf/
https://ovaismehboob.wordpress.com/2011/06/23/inspecting-messages-in-wcf/
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/06/28/wcf-extensibility-behavior-configuration-extensions/

It doesn't seem very difficult to setup. I am debugging in Visual Studio 2012. The behavior I'm seeing is that the BehaviorExtensionElement.BehaviorType method is being hit while debugging. However the EndPointBehavior methods are not being hit. I've checked the web.config multiple times to make sure values are setup properly. It appears that since the BehaviorType method is being hit, the web.config settings should be good. I've read many articles/threads about why this may not work, but have not made any progress.

I wanted to include exactly how I'm debugging this just to make sure I'm not missing something relative to debugging the service in Visual Studio. I highlight the .svc file in Solution Explorer and start the debugger which launches the Visual Studio web service test interface. While the interface is starting up, the BehaviorType method is hit. I then hit F5 about 4 times and the interface is fully rendered. I double click on one of my service methods, enter the required parameters and submit. My understanding of how this works is that I should hit the BeforeSendReply method in the custom endpoint behavior class. I have breakpoints on all of the methods in the class - even the non-implemented ones.

I also want to mention that the CreateBehavior method does not get hit.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: I decided to try to implement a service level behavior. This works as expected. However, I thought it would be best to implement an endpoint level behavior. I'm not sure why the service behavior works while the endpoint does not.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the endpoint behavior to work after going through different configurations in the web.config together with slightly different code.